# Função síncrona para assíncrona em c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma função em c# síncrona e funciona bem e com a mudança da reinf vai passar a assíncrona e não tenho mais retorno porque passou a ser `void`, não conheço webservice como faço pra ter o retorno do webservice ?
Ex:
Umm exemplo pra ver se você consegue me ajudar, esse era a função síncrona que funcionava bem até agora :

```cs
System.Xml.XmlNode xx;

xx = ConsultaReciboEvento4020(4020,xx,xx,xx,xx);

        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/ConsultasReinf/ConsultaReciboEvento4020", RequestNamespace = "http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/", ResponseNamespace = "http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public System.Xml.XmlNode ConsultaReciboEvento4020(int tipoEvento, byte tpInsc, string nrInsc, string dtApur, string nrInscEstabelecimento)
        {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("ConsultaReciboEvento4020", new object[] {
                        tipoEvento,
                        tpInsc,
                        nrInsc,
                        dtApur,
                        nrInscEstabelecimento});
            return ((System.Xml.XmlNode)(results[0]));
        }
```

E agora como assíncrona ficou dessa forma :

```cs
        public void ConsultaReciboEvento4020Async(int tipoEvento, byte tpInsc, string nrInsc, string dtApur, string nrInscEstabelecimento)
        {
            this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020Async(tipoEvento, tpInsc, nrInsc, dtApur, nrInscEstabelecimento, null);
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public void ConsultaReciboEvento4020Async(int tipoEvento, byte tpInsc, string nrInsc, string dtApur, string nrInscEstabelecimento, object userState)
        {
            if ((this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020OperationCompleted == null))
            {
                this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020OperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnConsultaReciboEvento4020OperationCompleted);
            }
            this.InvokeAsync("ConsultaReciboEvento4020", new object[] {
                        tipoEvento,
                        tpInsc,
                        nrInsc,
                        dtApur,
                        nrInscEstabelecimento}, this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020OperationCompleted, userState);
        }

        private void OnConsultaReciboEvento4020OperationCompleted(object arg)
        {
            if ((this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020Completed != null))
            {
                System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
                this.ConsultaReciboEvento4020Completed(this, new ConsultaReciboEvento4020CompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
            }
        }
```

E a chamada da função ficou dessa forma então não retorna nada.

```
ConsultaReciboEvento4020Async(4020,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx)
```

Comment: Por favor, leia a documentação do stack overflow para adequar seu código permitindo interação dos demais usuários. Coloque uma formatação/identação correta para entendimento do código C#.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o problema: o código que estamos vendo é do WebService ou é o seu sistema? Do meu ponto de vista não faz sentido uma chamada async retornar void, por padrão é retornada uma `Task` ou  `Task<TipoDoRetorno>`, poderia nos dar mais detalhes?

Answer (score -1):

Essa função não se tornou apenas assíncrona. Esta função está foi implementada no paradigma de eventos. Alguns nomes que podem te ajudar a entender esse paradigma é **CQRS** e **Event Sourcing**.

Contudo, não consigo te ajudar mais do que isso, pois não sei como lidar da forma correta neste modelo.

#### Possibilidades:

**OBS**: Não sei se é o jeito correto de se fazer.

Se eu não tivesse auxílio e precisasse trabalhar neste código, eu tentaria utilizar a função `ConsultaReciboEvento4020Async()` passando um `userData` que identificasse a operação que chamou esta função e mexeria na função ConsultaReciboEvento4020Completed().

Outra possibilidade é talvez instanciar a classe com estes métodos e atribuir um valor para a propriedade ConsultaReciboEvento4020Completed.

**OBS**: Novamente, estou apenas alucinando possibilidades, pois não conheço sua base de código e não sei exatamente como devo utilizar estes métodos.